# ArrayList elementData contains null after adding one element

Tags: java, arraylist

Declared

```
List list= new ArrayList<MyObject>();
MyObject mo = new MyObject();
mo.setFieldOne("A");

list.add(mo);
```

Why does results contain null elementData?

[image: results contains null elements, though arraylist.size(0) is only 1]

Comment: This is  internal array implementation. Its member variable objectData which happens to be the internal buffer of the ArrayList which actually stores elements you add.

Comment: just change List list= new ArrayList<MyObject>(); to ArrayList<MyObject> list= new ArrayList<MyObject>();